# iPhone as AirTunes receiver

Tags: iphone, ios, airtunes

Is there an app that will receive AirTunes? I want to use iOS4's new AirPlay capability to send audio from one iOS device to another. I realize I can use Rogue Amoeba's Airfoil and Speakers to stream from my Mac to said iPhone, but I want to send from my iPhone to another iPhone.

What I'm trying to do is avoid buying an Airport Express device by just hooking up an old iPhone and running an app...

Comment: What exactly do you want to send? iPod music from iPhone A to iPhone B? Since Airport Express doesn't have speakers, it's hard to map how an iPhone B will replace that item. I use a belkin bluetooth reciever to get sound from iPhone A to a mini jack which is more like the Airport Express functionality.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. With an Airport Express, I can hit the AirPlay button in any app in iOS4 and choose said AirPort Express as my output target. With speakers hooked into the AirPort Express's headphones jack, I then have wireless, remote audio that'll work without special software on the sending device.

I'd like to be able to target an old iPhone, running a theoretical "AirTunes receiver" app that would be hooked up to speakers via it's headphone jack. I'm just wondering if that "AirTunes receiver" app exists. Open Source or Jailbreak would be fine...

Comment: Got it. iPhone + software + speakers = JamBox over WiFi instead of Bluetooth. If no-one has any software, you could go with Belkin over bluetooth and connect it to your speakers, but that's an alternative, not an answer...

Comment: There was once a free app called AirView that did exactly what you're looking for, but it doesn't appear to be available any longer. I just did a search, and can't find it any longer. I suspect that something like this isn't really permitted, which is why there's a lack of options. Jailbreaking might be the best bet.

Comment: Just a side note from someone who has this working on their iDevices: when locked, neither the iPhone nor the iPad will play without constant dropouts (which are quite annoying). So while I love the feature (especially for piping audio anywhere), just be aware to have your iDevice unlocked prior to playing audio on it. Also recognize that there is a slight delay, so if you're trying to sync audio and video, you might have some fun with that (esp when using airfoil).

Comment: @Kerri, mind sharing how you have it working?

Comment: @RickDT If you use the link below (http://www.macstories.net/tutorials/how-to-turn-your-iphone-and-ipad-into-airplay-speakers/), it details how to get it working. I did have to go through some funny business to get mine happy, but I think it was because I tried to go another route. If you follow the directions, it *should* work, but if not, you may have to look into launching the airtunesd process manually (which will require a terminal app + OpenSSH installed) with "launchctl load -w com.apple.airtunesd.plist". (See: http://xsellize.com/topic/96599-o-airplayspeaker-v10-repo/page__st__20)

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to jailbreak your iPhone there is an app on Cydia that will turn your iPhone/iPod/iPad into an AirPlay speaker. It has its issues, but it works fairly well.

If you have want to mess with it there is an article here:

http://www.macstories.net/tutorials/how-to-turn-your-iphone-and-ipad-into-airplay-speakers/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have to wait for the iCloud (and even that isn't exactly what you ask since it won't likely be remote controllable and will require internet access).

No one has admitted to cracking this nut with a third party app.